# c++ syntax error help needed, missing ';' before '}'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
else if((RI >= 181) && (RI <= 210)){
        if((ICT1 = false) || ((ICT2 = false) || (ICT3 = false))){
        cout << "ICT \n";
        if(ICT1 = false){
            ICT1 = true;
            goto endICT;
        }
        if(ICT2 = false){
            ICT2 = true;
            goto endICT;
        }
        if(ICT3 = false){
            ICT3 = true;
            goto endICT;
        }
            endICT:
    }
```

Hi there!
This is just part of my program, and this bit of code appears a few times, with different variables and other stuff. When I compile the code, I get "error C2143: Syntax Error : missing ';' before '}'"
I'm new to all this coding, and would appreciate any help! 
Thanks for your time!
EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't include enough of the code before! Basically a random number is chosen, and if it's within a range, it goes through this part. This range can only be chosen 3 times, because then the first 'if' would not be true.
Thanks for all your help so far! Also the error is in the 'endICT:' line.

Comment: That `goto` is pointless.

Comment: This whole thing could be replaced by `ICT3 = true;` (assuming you meant `==` and not `=` in the if condition).

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is complaining about one of the lines you copied? It might make sense adding a bit of the context (lines before/after)

Comment: Labels must be *attached* to statements; they are not statements themselves.

Comment: You should also avoid using `goto`s (see http://xkcd.com/292/), and when posting errors please include the line number where the error occurred, and showing where this line is in the code you post.

Comment: @lxop, I wouldn't say to avoid `goto` completely (it does make code cleaner in specific situations), but people do use it a lot when it's not appropriate at all.

Comment: That `goto` is **either** pointless **or** masquerading as a `break;`

Comment: Did you actually mean what you said with "*this bit of code appears a few times*"?!

Answer (score 4):

Simply insert an empty statement:

```
                   if(ICT3 = false){
        ICT3 = true;
        goto endICT;
    }
        endICT: ;
}
```

Comment: Made this change, got rid of the error, but now i get no output at all. I think this is what i need, now need to find the new problem. Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

First of all note that it is considered to be a bad practice to use `goto` statement. It should only be used if there is no other option.

There are few more things to this code. I have commented some into the code

```
if(ICT3 = false) //this will assign value false into variable ICT3
     //you might want to write if(ICT3 == false) to compare and execute
{
   ICT3 = true;
   goto endICT; //this goto statement is completely redundant
}

//I assume that you want to have some code here, that does not execute
//if ICT3 == false in the first place... You should use if() ... else
//statement instead

endICT: ; //You are missing some ; here should be enough
}
```

for more information on flow control statements in C/C++ [go here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_control_statements.htm).
For more info about operators in C/C++ [try this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the compiler is confused with your label
    endICT:

which is followed by closing )

Answer (score 0):

This is semantically equivalent to your posted code:

```
else if ( RI >= 181 && RI <= 210 )
{
    cout << "ICT \n";
    if ( ! ICT1 )
        ICT1 = true;
    else if ( ! ICT2 )
        ICT2 = true;
    else if ( ! ICT3 )
        ICT3 = true;
}
```